# Pass list of categories to JS

Tags: categories, wp-localize-script

I'm trying to pass a list of all the categories to my MixItUp settings in my JS file to show all the items on load. But I can't seem to generate a list of the categories and reliably send them over to the JS file.

Here're how I've been trying to generate the categories.

```
function cats()
{
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args); 

    $slugs = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) 
        $slugs[] = $category->slug;

    return $slugs;

    print_r($slugs);
}
```

And once that works I figure I would need to send it via ?

```
wp_localize_script('main', 'cats', array( ) );
```

Comment: Change `$$args` to `$args`. And, `$images[]` to `$slugs[]` or vice versa. Regarding the use of `wp_localize_script` see the documentation and search the site, I'm certain you'll find what you need.

Comment: Fixed that error in the op. Was still not generating the list of categories.

Comment: Only thing I can say is, what you doing isn't wrong per se, so go on debug your steps.